# React Native Navigation Drawer Stuck on Splash Screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

The application gets stuck on the splash screen once it enters the component where the Drawer.Navigator is located. This issue occurs only when the app is installed via an APK; it doesn't fail in development mode.

*Navegation.jsx*

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import React from 'react';
import Main from './Main';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function NavegationDrawerSuplemente() {

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator 
    initialRouteName='Portada'
  >
 <Drawer.Screen name="Portada" component={Main}  
/>
 </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
export default NavegationDrawerSuplemente;
```

*Package.json*

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "expo": "^49.0.9",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.12",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.1",
    "react-native-progress-steps": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.15"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I've tried changing versions and checking for possible errors with ADB, but nothing has worked